# unable to launch R or reinstall R due to missing libblas.so.3gf

Tags: 16.04, package-management, dependencies, r

I've run following command:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

and I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
```

then run

```
sudo -i R
```

but it shows:

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: 
 libblas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the steps 
sudo apt-get purge r-base

If your are in 14.04:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9

gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install r-base
```

If you are in 16.04

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Answer (score 0):

libblas.so.3gf is provided by the package *revolution-mkl* (REvolution Computing high-performance numeric libraries for R) so install it. Run the following commands and comment if they give any error messages.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo apt install r-base-core r-revolution-core revolution-mkl
```